# Liquibase reading from phantom changelogs

Tags: java, spring-boot, liquibase

I'm creating a spring boot application and began messing around with liquibase to guarantee that all my tables where initialized on startup and got it working fine. Then made some changes to the changelog, erased the database and built my project through maven, still everything splendid. Aaand then my application exploded on startup with an error about checksums.

I tried, erasing the database again, clearing checksums through the maven plugin, syncing, nothing.
What I found strange, was that, when I deleted my changelog's content, it still built my database with the latest changes. So to test it out I changed the name of my changelog and the name of the changeset and boom:

> liquibase.exception.MigrationFailedException: Migration failed for changeset classpath:db_changelog.sqlite.sql::1::Example:
> Reason: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: [SQLITE_ERROR] SQL error or missing database (table example_table already exists) [Failed SQL: (1)

Where is liquibase getting these tables from!?

Liquibase bean config (I have even tried to exclude AutoConfiguration to force this config):

```
  @Bean
  public SpringLiquibase liquibase() {
    SpringLiquibase liquibase = new SpringLiquibase();
    liquibase.setChangeLog("classpath:db_changelog.sqlite.sql");
    liquibase.setDataSource(dataSource());
    return liquibase;
  }
```

Maven plugin config:

```
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
        <artifactId>liquibase-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${liquibase.version}</version>
        <configuration>
          <driver>org.sqlite.JDBC</driver>
          <changeLogFile>./src/main/resources/db_changelog.sqlite.sql</changeLogFile>
          <url>jdbc:sqlite:../database.db</url>
          <outputChangeLogFile>generatedChangelog.sqlite.sql</outputChangeLogFile>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the classpath context of liquibase executed from **maven** is different to one executed from **spring-boot** application. For example in maven, classpath to changeLog file could look like `/Users/you/app/src/main/resources/liquibase/changelog.xml` while in spring it could look like `resources/liquibase/changelog.xml`. I guess that this path is also included in the hash computation, therefore two identical changeSets are not identical anymore because of that path. Liquibase fixed that with [logicalfilepath](https://docs.liquibase.com/concepts/changelogs/attributes/logicalfilepath.html). So if you plan to execute LB from multiple tools, use that.

PS: use that property always and you have no problem ;)

Comment: While this awesome information and I thank you for it. It still doesn't answer the existence of the invisible changelogs. How can I still populate the database even if I delete everything (both database and changelogs)?

Comment: I quite don't understand what happened in your case. If you are able to reproduce that from beginning with clear steps maybe I can help...but not with the description which you wrote sorry.

Comment: I have no idea myself to be honest. I suspect that it had something to do with the path I was defining, but will have to test it at a later date.
For now, I changed my paths to relative ones (jdbc:sqlite:database.db) and everything seems to be working fine thanks to your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Liqudbase creates two tables in your database one is `databasechangelog` and the other one is `databasechangeloglock`. The first one is the one that holds every single scrip entry and it checks if this script has been executed before or not. Now if you have already executed a script and would change its content without changing file name you would get a check sum error. My guess would be that you did precisely that.

Comment: Not only did I change the filename, I also deleted my database completely. It's a sqlite database, so I normally delete the .db file when I want to start from scratch